# Using existing Windows OS (that I can't boot into anymore) as a virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

I have a drive with my operating system on it (Windows 7) that I can't boot into anymore because my motherboard fried.  I don't need any data, I just want to boot into the OS once to copy some application settings.  I have a new Win 10 desktop, and a macbook running OSX 10.7.5.  How can I boot into this drive using these?

I'm thinking the only way is to use VMWare or Parallels to create a virtual machine, but as far as I know I need to boot into that drive in order to create the virtual machine.

I've tried installing my drive into the desktop, but it can't boot and I'm assuming its a hardware compatibility issue.  When I put it into an external enclosure, I can't boot in either.  I can access the files as if its an external mass storage device, but I need to boot in, the files are already backed up on an external.  Any suggestions are welcome.

The old motherboard had a bios while the new one is UEFI.  Could this be the reason I can't boot?

Comment: Have you checked drive for errors?

Comment: Changes of hardware environment *MIGHT* requires you to fix the boot files (e.g. BCD store), no matter if it's VM or "PM" (VM also have emulated hardwares). It's better to give descriptions and details about HOW it `can't boot`, otherwise suggestions will only be random and wild.

Comment: Also `I need to boot into that drive in order to create the virtual machine` doesn't sound making any sense.

Comment: Error 1962: no operating system found. Boot sequence will automatically repeat". I then went into the UEFI of my computer and changed the boot order as well as allowed legacy systems (since it was disabled). When I did this, I didn't receive any error, but nothing happened. It wouldn't boot into the OS, and eventually just leaves me at a blank screen.  The drive is fine, it doesn't turn up any errors.

Comment: @TomYan  When I ran Parallels on my mac, it required me to install a transporter file on the existing bootable OS in order to create the virtual machine.